# routing with landing pages

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular2-routing

In my SPA application I have navigation:

```
+-- Home (route: /)
+-- System Information (route: /sys-info/)
  +-- System (route: /sys-info/system)
  +-- Health (route: /sys-info/health)
+-- Settings (route: /settings)
```

I need to have landing page for `System information` section listing subsections (`System`, `Health`) each with description.

On this landing page there will be also checkbox "Don't show again" with value stored in localStorage. If checked then first section should show on navigating to route `/sys-info/`.

Each subsection screen will look similar: left side panel with navigation menu and main panel with content. In navigation menu there will be all subsections (`System`, `Health`) with current one highlighted (side menu allowing to navigate between subsections).

So far in main `app.component.ts` I've got `@RouteConfig`:

```
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
},
{
    path: '/system-information/...',
    name: 'SystemInformation',
    component: SystemInformationComponent
},
{
    path: '/settings',
    name: 'Settings',
    component: SettingsComponent
}
```

and in template I have tag `<router-outlet>` under menu.

`@RouteConfig` in `SystemInformationComponent`:

```
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'SysInfoLanding',
    component: SysInfoLandingComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
},
{
    path: '/system',
    name: 'SysInfoSystem',
    component: SystemComponent
},
{
    path: '/health',
    name: 'SysInfoHealth',
    component: HealthComponent
}
```

And in template I've got left side menu and right container for content with tag `<router-outlet>`. But I don't know how to prepare html for this landing page.

When solved I will need copy the solution to other items in main menu - preferably prepare reusable components. `Settings` also has subitems - don't show here to preserve readability.

Comment: Well, this should work as it is. With what HTML do you have problems exactly?

Comment: @rinukkusu when I want to render landing page I also have side navigation but I need to have landing page full-screen - inside top router-outlet

Comment: A solution came to my mind - hide the left-side navigation while being on landing page. It should work but does not look pro for me.